# How can I adjust my code to adapt the Django upgrade?

Tags: python, django

```
from django.template.base import TagHelperNode, VariableNode
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name TagHelperNode
```

I had upgrade Django from 1.8.14 to 1.11.17

Comment: I had checked the release notes from 1.8.15 to 1.11.17, It seems that no change about TaghelperNode class. I hope someone will help me, thanks very much!

Comment: Django changes and migration path are well documented for each release. Don't try to jump directly from 1.8.x to 1.11.x, follow the whole migration path (1.8.x -> 1.9.x -> 1.10.x -> 1.11.x) and you'll be fine (from experience, this __will__ be both faster and simpler).

Comment: Yeah, Bruno, thanks for your advice, that's scientific, but we have to upgrade Django to 1.11.15+ to solve the security issue, and there is no much time to let me try it.

Comment: Do what you want, but going straight from 1.8 to 1.11 is not going to be faster than doing it incrementally - at least if you care about shipping working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
from django.template.library import TagHelperNode
```

Reference can be found [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.17/django/template/library.py#L195).

Comment: Thanks, Ruddra, it works. But I got a new error  """ from django.template.debug import DebugVariableNode
ImportError: No module named debug""", it seems that the debug module was retired.